# How to loop across text input in a text area and insert links based on a JSON string in an HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, textarea

How to achieve that text is looped across and (glossary) links available in e. g. a JSON string are inserted in this text:

- in an HTML, there are 2 text areas and 1 button
- in one text area, plain text like the following can be inserted:

  ```
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...
  ```
- the click on the button triggers the following: the text inserted in the text area is looped across and if words (or consecutive words!) have a match (should be case insensitive) in the JSON string, the corresponding value (in this case, it is an HTML link) should be inserted in the text
- the final text with the link replacements should then be displayed in the second text area

Example:
A json string might look like this:

```
const myJSON = '{"lorem":"<a href="some_url">lorem</a>", 
                 "ipsum":"<a href="some_url">ipsum</a>",
                 "lorem ipsum":"<a href="some_url">lorem ipsum</a>",
                 "amet":"<a href="some_url">amet</a>",
                 "elit":"<a href="some_url">elit</a>"}';
```

The expected outcome should be this. One of the challenges, I might think, is dealing with "lorem ipsum" (instead of having two individual links in the text for "lorem" and "ipsum"). The initial lower case of "lorem" is irrelevant.

```
<a href="some_url">lorem ipsum</a>" dolor sit 
<a href="some_url">amet</a>, consectetur adipiscing <a href="some_url">elit</a>...
```

Has anyone tips or even a code snippet? thx.

Comment: Tip: sort your replacements so that lorem doesn't get replaced before lorem ipsum.

Comment: Sometimes you have to ask yourself: how can I enhance my input to make my life easier? This seems a case of 'garbage in, garbage out'.